# Some questions about ASP.Net Postback

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, user-controls

Lets say I have a text box which should have a default value.... and it is in an initializing function like so:

```
void InitializeControls()
{
    myTextBox.Text = "Default Text";
}
```

Now, lets say that I have a button, which does a postback...  I want to save the user entered value of the textbox off somewhere in the button's OnClick event.

My question is, when should I call the initializing control code above?  I'm thinking it should be in the OnLoad function, however this seems like that I will overwrite the postback data everytime:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    base.OnLoad(eventArgs);

    InitializeControls();
}
```

Will the postback data overwrite my default text above if I have the initializing code in the OnLoad?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `InitializeControls()` in the `OnInit`, before the call to `base.OnInit()`. In this way your default value will not be part of the ViewState and you will not be passing it to the client and back for no reason.
You could also just set the default value in the mark-up (in the .aspx file).

Do *not* call InitializeControls() in PageLoad / OnLoad since this will add the default value to ViewState, bloating ViewState for no reason.

Read the article [TRULY understanding ViewState](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) to get a good understanding of this stuff.

Answer (score 4):

The user-entered value of the textbox will be lost during the postback if you set the text manually by calling InitializeControl() in Page_Load.

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ms972976.viewstate_fig02%28en-us,MSDN.10%29.gif))</sub>

Per durilai's comment, place inside a `!IsPostBack` if-block the code that you want to happen only when the page loads for the first time:

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
    InitializeControls();
}
```

Comment: So I should only be setting default values if it is not postbacK?  What about with dynamic controls?

Comment: unless you wrap it with if (!ispostback)

Comment: Setting the value in Page_Load will cause it to be tracked by ViewState for no reason, thus enlarging ViewState unnecessarily. The default value should be set in OnInit before the call to base.OnInit (after the call to base.OnInit() ViewState starts tracking changes)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are probably looking for the code

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
```

Which allows you to deal with those things that should only happen on first load.

Comment: So when do postback values actually get loaded?  What about if the controls are dynamic?

Comment: I'm asking because I'd like to know if I can just call this function in OnInit or something and the postback values will just overwrite the defaults... which is ideal

Comment: Dynaically added controls will be different, depending on where in the page lifecycle you have added them to the control hierarchy...

Answer (score 0):

You could also just set the default value in the textbox in your markup, then you wouldn't need to worry about setting default values in your code and checking for a post back.  Otherwise, Page_Load and OnLoad are both appropriate places to set the default values. You'll want to check if the page has posted back, and if so, don't overwrite the user's value:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    InitializeControls();
```