# Table not updated despite command being correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I use a stored procedure for inserting, updating and deleting records, and I use LINQ for executing or calling the procedures.
After clicking on submit button, the update procedure has been executed but there is no change in the table!
If I pass a value like "Jack" instead of fname_txt.text, it works and is updated.
I don't know what's the different between a textbox object and a value in a quotation mark?!
Here is the code:

```
    protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            ZobLinqDataContext db = new ZobLinqDataContext();
            string pasword = CryptorEngine.Encrypt(pass_txt.Text, true);
            long uid = Convert.ToInt64(Request["uid"]);
            db.pUpZDBUser(uid,
                uname_txt.Text,
                pasword,
                fname_txt.Text.Trim(),
                lname_txt.Text.Trim(),
                modir.Checked,
                voting.Checked,
                Convert.ToInt32(Zarib_txt.Text),
                false
                );
            db.SubmitChanges();
            Response.Write(uname_txt);
        }
        finally
        {
            Session["sub"] = "1";
        }

    }
```

this is the update proc:

```
    USE [ZOBDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[pUpZDBUser]    Script Date: 04/11/2012 15:17:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pUpZDBUser] 
    @UID bigint,
    @Uname  nvarchar(100),
    @Pass   nvarchar(100),
    @fname  nvarchar(50),
    @lname  nvarchar(50),
    @KU bit,
    @KV bit,
    @ZribV  int,
    @del bit
As
BEGIN TRANSACTION UpUser    
    Set NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE Users SET 
        Uname=@Uname, 
        Pass=@Pass, 
        fname=@fname, 
        lname=@lname, 
        KU=@KU, 
        KV=@KV, 
        ZribV=@ZribV,
        del=@del
    where (UID=@UID)

    --RollBack if Err
    IF @@ERROR != 0 and @@ROWCOUNT != 1
    BEGIN
        declare @msg nvarchar(30)
        set @msg = ' error '+@Uname
        ROLLBACK
        RAISERROR(@msg,16,1)
        RETURN
    END
COMMIT TRANSACTION UpUser
RETURN
```

Comment: Can you please also post the SQL PROC associated with pUpZDBUser method on the context?

Comment: This is .NET not ASP Classic.

Comment: I've added the proc, tnx for answering, @nonnb

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have more luck if you change the SPROC to

```
--RollBack if Err     
IF @@ERROR != 0 **OR** @@ROWCOUNT != 1
```

This way you should get the error being raised and you can see what the issue is.
Possibly the UID doesn't exist?

Comment: No, It exists. As I said if it be db.pUpZDBUser(uid,"Jack", ...) instead of db.pUpZDBUser(uid, fname_txt.text, ...) it works correctly.
@nonnb

Comment: Try it. If @@ERROR is non zero, then the row count is likely to be zero. And if the update updated zero rows, then ERROR will likely be zero. Meaning that your error is NEVER raised.

Comment: I changed my code to yours run updating code as uasual, but there is no error.
I'm completely confused.
It seems that the button sends empty object values, but the "uid" is not empty because it is a form request, but I don't know why it thinks that the text boxes are empty and sends empty values?!
@nonnb

Comment: I found the problem but I don't know what should I do!

Its an Update page, I send the selected user ID that has selected by user on the previous page that users information have been listed.

In this page(Update page), on form load event I bind the information of the selected ID to the text boxes and other objects, so after changing the values of text boxes and other objects by user, when I click on submit button it sends the values that have bound on the form load not the values that user has typed.

So, what should I do?

@nonnb

Comment: It sounds like you are overwriting the postback fields with initialization fields. You need to initialize your form variables either in OnInit or in Page Load only if (!IsPostBack) .. Have a look at the page lifecycle here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx and this SO Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471294/some-questions-about-asp-net-postback

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is that your proc is throwing an exception that you're not catching, perhaps because there's a length constraint on the column, and that your `fname_txt.Text.Trim()` value is zero length, and "Jack" of course is not.

Add a catch block to your code to prover there is nothing untoward happening in your proc. Also more detail in your question would be helpful.

Comment: NO, there is no exception. I'd tried it and there was no exception.
About fname_txt, the problem is about all parameter not only for this one. for example uname_txt.Text or lname_txt include this problem too.
@Ralph Shilington